# Searching multiple tables at the same time in a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sequelize.js

I am trying to search the database column called "equipment" for multiple table models using sequelize. However, I am not receiving any data even though the fields are full. I am attempting to use the "Promise".

However, if I simply call the model ( //boilerHouse.findAll({ where: { equipment_type: { [Op.in]: [req.params.name] } } }).then((data) => { ), I can search one table but not all.

```
router.get("/equipmentInfo/:name", (req, res) =>

 Promise.all([boilerHouse.findAll({ where: { equipment_area: { [Op.in]: [req.params.name] } } }), compressorHouse.findAll({ where: { equipment_area: { [Op.in]: [req.params.name] } } }), engineHouse33.findAll({ where: { equipment_area: { [Op.in]: [req.params.name] } } }), fireHouse.findAll({ where: { equipment_area: { [Op.in]: [req.params.name] } } }), hfoSeparator.findAll({ where: { equipment_area: { [Op.in]: [req.params.name] } } }), reverseOsmosis.findAll({ where: { equipment_area: { [Op.in]: [req.params.name] } } }), tankFarm33.findAll({ where: { equipment_area: { [Op.in]: [req.params.name] } } }) ])
.then((data) => {

  //boilerHouse.findAll({ where: { equipment_type: { [Op.in]: [req.params.name] } } }).then((data) => {

    res.render('gigs', {
      gigs:data,

     //data[0] is response from tableA find
     // data[1] is from tableB
      })   
    }).catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Javascript developer but if I had the same problem I will do the following:

1. I will make a function of what I need to search and where to search as parameters
2. create multiple processes for all the places where I need to search It called **asynchronous programming**
3. wait for responses of all processes then return the responses to the main process
4. Then do the rest of work

Is like process 4 requests once at the same time without waiting to others to finish